# Integral of an odd function doesn't converge

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I have a function $y(x)=\frac{x}{1+x^2}, x\in Reals$, it is an odd function, with no undefined points, so I expect its integral (in the range $[-\infty,+\infty]$) to be 0. But when I use Mathematica to calculate it,

```
Integrate[x/(1+x^2),{x,-Infinity,Infinity}]
```

It says 'Integral of  $y(x)=\frac{x}{1+x^2}$ does not converge on $[-\infty,+\infty]$'.

Comment: Also, `Integrate[x/(1+x^2), {x, -max, max}]` evaluates to zero and its limit as `max -> Infinity` is also zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Integrate[x/(1 + x^2), {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
 PrincipalValue -> True]

Out[1]= 0
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, I tried this and it works. But could you explain a little bit more about the 'principalvalue'?

Comment: @dr.bian It is well known, if the Riemann integral diverges, then the Cauchy integral may converge. Your intuition tells you "it is an odd function, with no undefined points, so I expect its integral to be 0". Mathematica answers you "the Cauchy principal value integral =0".

Comment: Ah,I will see more on this, Thanks!

Comment: @dr.bian You're welcome!